# Scaling the height of the background for different resolution

Tags: css, background

I would like my background image to scale itself to fit the screen for different resolutions. I'm not looking for something like *background-size: cover*, I always want to see a full view of my background image.

For example, if my background was just an image of a tree that's like 500x1000, I always want to see the whole tree on the background, not scaled to make it full page and show only the portion of the tree.

I tried different things with *background-size:* but nothing seems to work.
Here's what I have in my CSS

```
body 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fffff;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-image:url(main_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain Auto;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: Just found a solution to my problem. I had to move all of background properties into html part of the css not the body :P

Comment: it should be background-size:100% Auto; contain and cover apply for both axys

Answer (score 1):

You should try putting 100% height for html and body, then attempt to size the image

```
html,body {height:100%;}
```

-

```
body 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fffff;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-image:url(main_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

or

```
body 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fffff;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-image:url(main_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Comment: Just tried this method but it still scaled up the image so I could only see the top portion of it.

Comment: try `background-position:bottom;`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do:

```
background-size: 100%
```

Comment: That does fill the whole page with the image but when I maximize my browser, it only shows the top portion of the image. I want to see the whole image no matter the size of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <img src='main_bg.jpg'>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow-y: hidden;
}

img {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

If it does not suit for you, 'only' JavaScript can help you.